# Should i pay for transportation after work time

Tags: compensation

Recently I and my team leader had meeting with a client. We used public transport to get to clients place. I don't have any public transport pass, so my company provided me with one ticket. Meeting has ended at the time when my work hours ends, so we were not going back to office. To get home I also needed a ticket, so I bought one.

Can I ask company for compensation?

Since it happened for first time I don't worry about money much, I want to know how to manage situations like this if it happens again.

Comment: What was the difference in cost vs your normal commute home?

Comment: @motosubatsu i don't have any expenses. Office is not far from my place so I just walk

Comment: I think the company should pay

Comment: The company normally pays you for any official/client visits, no harm in asking.

Comment: @Markus in that case I would say the company should pay really - with the caveat that it should only be up to the amount that it would have cost you to get back to the office if that makes sense.

Comment: Every company is different, my guess would be because you normally walk home anyway, it slipped their mind. Chances are, if they paid one way, they would more than likely pay both ways. Just be polite when ask and just tell them if the transportation if only covered for one way, you will have to make travel arrangements to get home.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Can I ask company for compensation?
>
> Since it happened for first time I don't worry about money much, I
>   want to know how to manage situations like this if it happens again.

You can always ask.

Most companies I know of would pay your transportation costs to and from a client site. Even though you traveled home, my companies would have compensated you for your ticket costs. The same would hold true if it was public transportation or an airplane.

This may be a matter of local law, but is at least a matter of company policy.

Ask so that you'll know for the future.